# Request for help to understand the behaviour of the .. operator in the given code

Tags: perl

When I run the code shown below

```
use 5.14.0;
print("\n");
print(join("  ", ("A01".."A10")), "\n");
print("\n");
print(join("  ", ("A_01".."A_10")), "\n");
print("\n");
```

I get

```
A01  A02  A03  A04  A05  A06  A07  A08  A09  A10

A_01
```

The output of uname -a is pasted below.

```
Linux n51958 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Why is the underscore in the from and to strings making such a difference?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks TLP and Danny Staple. That explains it. I will work around it as suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is described in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

```
The range operator (in list context) makes use of the magical auto-increment 
algorithm if the operands are strings. You can say

    @alphabet = ("A" .. "Z");

to get all normal letters of the English alphabet, 

...

If the initial value specified isn't part of a magical increment sequence (that 
is, a non-empty string matching /^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/ ), only the initial value 
will be returned.
```

Answer (score 2):

From the perl doc on the operator (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html - under heading "range operators"):

> If the initial value specified isn't part of a magical increment sequence (that is, a non-empty string matching /^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/ ), only the initial value will be returned. So the following will only return an alpha

Perhaps you may want to substitute the "A" for "A_" with a regexp over the output or join the "A" back in later.